# Normalized vector cross product non-zero vector (unnormalized vector)

Tags: math, vector

It is clear to me that if we cross product two vectors, let say AxB then we will get a new vector C that perpendicular to A and B (either in the positive or negative position).
That's OK!
Also, it's clear to me the differences between unit vector and non-zero vector.
The unit vector is the result of normalizing a non-zero vector and we can say the unit vector is the vector divided by its length.

My question is:

If we have two vectors, one of them is a unit vector and the other one is a non-zero vector.
Let say A is the unit vector and B is the non-zero vector in this example.

- Can we cross product them (unit vector x non-zero vector)? Or we must
  normalize the non-zero vector?

If we must normalize the non-zero vector. Why must we do so?

Comment: This might belong better on the Mathematics SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a practical programming question, as described in the [help].

Comment: This question helped me answer the practical programming question of "Do I need to waste performance normalizing these two vectors before calculating their cross product.".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cross product of two vectors always is orthogonal to the two input vectors. Its magnitude will be |u| |v| sin θ, where θ is the (signed) angle between the two input vectors.

If you're looking for a unit vector perpendicular to two arbitrary input vectors, it's best to compute the cross product and then normalize, since if you normalize the vectors and then take the cross product the resulting vector isn't guaranteed to be a unit vector.